# unable to find the button below using selenium java webdriver

Tags: selenium

i'm using selenium, but unable to find the button below using findElement(By.xpath ... Could someone provide some help? Thanks very much!

```
<button type='button' class='pzhc' data-ctl data-click='[["processAction", ["LookUpPreview","true",":event","","Rule-HTML-Section"]]]'  ><div class='pzbtn-lft'  ><div class='pzbtn-rgt'><div class='pzbtn-mid' data-click='...'><img src='webwb/zblankimage.gif' class='pzbtn-i'/> Lookup</div></div></div></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the class name:

`WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("pzhc"));`